# How to constrain SQL tables to multiple specific types

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, constraints

I have a small database that I'm developing SQL Server 2008.

I don't have much SQL experience overall, so finding it difficult to find information as to what the appropriate pattern for this issue is.

[image]

The main table is 'Provider' a Provider can be a 'MatchService', a 'CompareService', or both depending on 'ProviderTypeId'. I'm looking to contrain data in the MatchService and CompareService tables based on the following rules:

1) A Provider with a ProviderTypeId = Lender can be both a MatchService and a CompareService;

2) A Provider with a ProviderTypeId = Pingtree can only be a MatchService.

I know that a solution probably includes a bridge table in the schema but I'm unsure as to what and where. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Well this coul be handled in the INSERT trigger instead. However since there is no more information required matchservice and compareservice I would rather go for only one table and use bit fields in that.

However should you have more information into those (MS and CS tables) it would be good to have seperate tables as you have created now.

Comment: @ChristerBacklundHøllesli - Sorry Christer, the above may be misleading. I've removed all other fields for brevity in the above example. The tables will contain unique data too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maby something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MatchService_ITrig
ON MatchService
FOR INSERT
AS
IF NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT
                        ProviderID
                    FROM
                        Provider p
                    INNER JOIN
                        inserted i ON
                            P.ID = I.ProviderID
                    WHERE
                        ProviderTypeID = 'Lender' OR
                        ProviderTypeID = 'PingTree'
                )
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

Comment: And also have an equal trigger for the compareservice table. Only change the where clause.

Comment: Notice that if you have bulk inserts this will have to be handled a litle differently...

Comment: Christer - i'm a bit of a noob, so I don't always know what is good or bad, better or best, but I thank you for pointing this out. I've implemented your solution and updated the answer accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about :

```
ALTER TABLE CompareService
ADD CONSTRAINT chkPTID CHECK (ProviderTypeId = Lender);
GO
```

Raj

Comment: Well, this will not work since he dont have the providertypeid in that table I suspect.

Comment: If we add the ProviderTypeId create an FK between Provider and CompareService on ProviderId and ProviderTypeId, we can do this and it provides the easiest solution.